# How to return arraylist as ints

Tags: java

I am trying to make an array that starts at a certain number, does it x times based on params passed in, and increments to add another number. I have created the array correctly but I have to return the array. I've looked up videos and read articles and cant figure it out. 
example createArray(0, 5, 3) will return an array containing {0, 3, 6, 9, 12} starts with number 0, then adds 3 and so on to make an array length of 5. 
The error that I get is error:

> incompatible types: ArrayList cannot be converted to int

```
class Utility{
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //TESTcreateArray(1, 3, 2);
  }

    public static int createArray(int start, int count, int step){
        int i=0;
        int startingNumber=start;
        int increment=step;
        ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //int x=arrList;

        while (i<count){
            arrList.add(startingNumber);
            startingNumber+=step;
            i++;
       }
        //TESTSystem.out.println(arrList);
        return arrList;
   } 
}
```

Comment: The return type of the method is incorrect. You have to change it to ArrayList<Integer>

Comment: The error message is incredibly clear: *ArrayList cannot be converted to int*

Comment: 3.5 weeks into Java, so still learning but even after converting it to public static ArrayList<Integer>createArray(int start, int count, int step){ it still fails my instructors tests, but when I print the array it has the right results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your:

```
public static int createArray(int start, int count, int step)
```

TO:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> createArray(int start, int count, int step)
```

Comment: Thanks, I found that right after i posted this I did public static ArrayList<Integer>createArray(int start, int count, int step){    but it still fails my instructors tests, but prints correctly.

Comment: Glad to be of help